# Prevent the UAC window for standard/common programs for all User accounts

Tags: windows, uac

All non-metro programs/software are installed from the Admin account, and shortcuts are also available in the Windows Start menu for each User account on that PC.

However, clicking on some of the shortcuts from any non-admin account calls up the UAC (User Account Control) window asking for Admin credentials to start the related program. Obviously, the Admin account credentials ***cannot be provided*** to all Users!

How can the UAC be avoided for selective programs ***so that all Users accounts are able to "freely" utilize these programs***?

***For example, the Microsoft Office programs or the Web Browsers etc. do not call up the UAC window, and it does not matter which User account it is***.

Comment: Windows 10 and 11 security prevents this. An Evergreen question.

Comment: Please describe the situation in greater detail and name a program that is affected. It is *highly* improbable that (reasonably modern) "plain old software" would bring up a UAC prompt.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

In order to solve the problem, one need to understand why the UAC dialog pops up.

At the start of the program, the program tells the operating system what it wants to do. This for example can be writing to a file in its directory, or writing to the registry.

If the useraccount does not have rights to any of the actions the program requests, Windows knows administrative privileges are needed in order to make it work anyway. Thus, a UAC dialog pops up, requesting elevated rights to solve the problem temporarily.

## Sidenote

Now, it really does depends on which program and what it wants to do, to determine if this can be fixed easily.

## User rights

When it comes to writing to disk, users have full access rights to their own folder in C:\Users\Username. Most programs that keep limited useraccounts in mind will write user settings to the %appdata% and %localappdata% folder respectively. These are usually browsers and MS Office.

When it comes to writing to the registry, users have full access to the HKEY_CURRENT USER hive. Most programs that keep limited useraccounts in mind will write user settings to KHEY_CU\SOFTWARE...

However, C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files (x86) are not accessible for writing to users without administrative access.

## Administrative rights

Programs that will require administrative rights are maintenance programs. They need full access to whatever they maintain, and thus also need access to restrictive areas of the computer. For example: defrag, disk management, backup, etc... Other programs can be programs that need to start/stop services. For example, they have a database and control the database through a service.

## What you can try

Now, in most cases when software asks for rights, but the software itself does not seem to actually do anything to maintain the system, it is usually that the software tries to write to the install location. For example to perform an update. In most cases, the software is installed to C:\Program Files or its x86 counterpart. By default users don't have write access to these folders and users with local admin privileges still get the UAC prompt but just can click yes.

If this is the case, you can fix this by having a user with administrative access change the folder security for the program's folder by giving the Users group write access.

Right-click the folder, properties, security tab.

This is not something you want to do for the whole program files folder though, only for that one program that gives the UAC prompt.

Here's an image (in dutch, sorry don't have access to an english system) of what you'd change:

[image]

You basically place a checkmark for the group Users on the modify one. The other checkboxes may be dimmed (inherited permissions). The modify one will be black.

It is possible to do the same for the registry, but the problem with the registry is figuring out what key the program wants to write to. Because it is very hard to figure that out, I left out that part from the answer. In 90% of all cases though, changing security permissions on the folder is enough, and on only 3% of all cases, is the problem registry permissions.

Comment: I’d like to clear up a slight misconception here: Programs do not declare what they want to access and then the UAC dialog pops up or not. Programs may declare they need admin rights, then the UAC dialog pops up. Programs can also decide to re-launch themselves elevated later, but this isn’t as common, because the state will be lost or must be transferred. Then there’s also setup detection in Windows for legacy software. It only applies to applications without a modern manifest.

Answer (score -1):

The UAC dialog is prompted when an application needs Administrator
permissions. It cannot be avoided unless you degrade the UAC protection
(not recommended).

There exist products that allow running specific applications as
Administrator without the user knowing the administrator password.
Such a product can solve your problem.

Some free products that do that :

- [RunAsTool](https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-5/)
- [RunAsRob](https://robotronic.net/runasroben.html)
- [Run As GUI](https://web.archive.org/web/20200318075026/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Run-As-GUI-b23012b2)
  This link is to the Internet Archives, as the original website
  has disappeared. You need to right-click on the Zip file to download.

Comment: Why is this downvoted???

Comment: I assume because of this incorrect sentence: " It cannot be avoided unless you degrade the UAC protection (not recommended)." In many cases, I've been able to make modifications to stop the UAC prompt by solving the root cause without lowering the UAC settings at all. Just some folder security permissions.

Comment: @LPChip: Not incorrect, unless one is willing to do the detective work in your answer, which anyway isn't sure to help. I'm very much against modifying permissions on protected folders or registry, so for me this phrase is true. Modifying permissions is one way of degrading the UAC.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with you, but anyway. The biggest problem here is that not every program is written correctly (or sometimes its written for older OSses that simply worked differently) and a hack like yours or mine is necessary.